# ExtraReducers is not working in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have setup redux store using redux-toolkit library.

This is index.ts

```js
const createStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: false,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => {
      const middleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
        immutableCheck: false,
        serializableCheck: false,
      });
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
        middleware.push(logger);
      }
      return middleware;
    },
  });

export const store = createStore();
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

This is rootReducer.ts

```js
import { combineReducers, Reducer, AnyAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import userCompnaySlice from "./slices/userCompnaySlice";

const userCompanyDataPersistConfig = {
  key: "userCompanyData",
  storage,
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  userCompany: persistReducer(userCompanyDataPersistConfig, userCompnaySlice.reducer),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof appReducer>;

const rootReducer: Reducer = (state: RootState, action: AnyAction) =>
  appReducer(state, action);

export default rootReducer;
```

This is userCompanySlice.ts:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { userCompanyReducer } from "../../utils/types/reducerStateTypes";
import { getCompanyInfo } from "../thunks/userCompanyThunk";

const initialState: userCompanyReducer = {
  userInfo: {},
  companyInfo: {},
};

const userCompanySlice = createSlice({
  name: "userCompany",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUserInfo: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo = action.payload;
    },
    setCompanyInfo: (state, action) => {
      state.companyInfo = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getCompanyInfo.pending.type]: (state, action) => {
        console.log("pending");
    },
    [getCompanyInfo.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
        console.log("fulfilled");
      state.companyInfo = action.payload;
    },
    [getCompanyInfo.rejected.type]: (state, action) => {
        console.log("rejected");
    },
  },
});

export const { setUserInfo, setCompanyInfo } = userCompanySlice.actions;

export default userCompanySlice;
```

This is userCompanyThunk.ts file:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axiosApiInstance from "../../services/axios";
import { companyAPI } from "../../shared/api/apiRoutes";

export const getCompanyInfo = createAsyncThunk(
  "userCompany/getCompanyInfo",
  async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosApiInstance.get(companyAPI);
      console.log(response.data["data"]);
      console.log("Action type:", getCompanyInfo.fulfilled.type);
      return response.data["data"];
    } catch (e: any) {
    //   if (e.response.status >= 400 && e.response.status < 599) {
    //     throw new Error(e.response.data.message);
    //   }
    console.log(e);
    }
  }
);
```

Now when I call `getCompanyInfo` it executes successfully & also printing the response.
But this is not invoked in `extraReducers` in `userCompanySlice.ts`.

This is how I'm executing `getCompanyInfo`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("get company");
  dispatch(getCompanyInfo());
  getCompany();
}, [dispatch]);
```

The function executes in `useEffect` & also prints the response got from API but does not invoke the `extraReducer`. Hence the state does not get updated.

I want the `extraReducers` to work when `getCompanyInfo` is called & set the `companyInfo` state.

I have used a similar aproach in my previous project & just copy pasted it in this project, but for some reason it doesn't work here.

Comment: The `extraReducers` should use the `builder` syntax, but I see other have already suggested this to you and your only response is to continue saying "it's not working". Can you [edit] the post with the builder syntax you've tried? Are there any errors in the console? What debugging steps have you taken already in trying to resolve this issue? If you still need more help then it might be helpful if you could try creating a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you are seeing that we could then inspect live.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I think Update your code Extra reducer code. Here is the example

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => state + 1,
    decrement: (state) => state - 1,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(someAction, (state, action) => {
        // Handle the additional action
      })
      .addCase(anotherAction, (state, action) => {
        // Handle another additional action
      });
  },
});

export const { increment, decrement } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Did not work. I have tried this before

Answer (score 1):

Hello Update your extra reducers syntax like below

```js
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
    .addCase(getCompanyInfo.pending.type, (state, action) => {
      console.log("pending");
    })
    
  },
```

Comment: Did not work. I have tried this before

Comment: @Sankethn it is still the correct notation. The notation you are using is deprecated and will be removed in RTK 2.0.